# Use only local beans inside the submodule in spring-boot multimodule project

Tags: spring, gradle, rabbitmq

I create the `Spring boot` application with two submodules: sumboduleEmail and submoduleSms. Each submodule have `@Configuration` file that create beans.

```
-root
  - SpringBootApplicationClass
  | - submoduleEmail
  | -   QueueEmail.java
  | -   ExchangeEmail.java
  | -   Config.java

  | - submoduleTwo
  | -   QueueSms.java
  | -   ExchangeSms.java
  | -   Config.java
```

In each config file:

```
@Bean("emailQueue") or ("smsQueue")
public Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(configProperties.getQueue());
}

@Bean("emailExchange") or ("smsExchange")
public DirectExchange exchange() {
    return new DirectExchange(configProperties.getExchange());
}

@Bean("emailBinding") or ("smsBinding")
public Binding binding() {
    return BindingBuilder
            .bind(queue())
            .to(exchange())
            .with(configProperties.getRoutingKey());
}
```

Due to the fact that the Spring starts from the root of the project, he sees all beans from all submodules.

I'm trying to bind my local `Exchange`-bean with my local `Queue`-bean inside local Email-submodule.

If not to use `Qualifier`-annotations, I expect a binding of only local beans from a local submodule. But Spring-boot have beans from self global context with another submodule beans and bind wrong beans. Because of this, I get the wrong binding.

First solve of this problem - use `Qualifier` annotation, like in example.

But how to say to Spring boot that he must use only local beans in local submodule, not using `Qualifier`-annotations?